# Firebase database - filtering and ordering query

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a React Native app, and trying to set up a user research in the database, based on a given text.

Here is my request code :

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('allUsers');
const query = ref.orderByChild("name").startAt(text).endAt(text+'\uf8ff').limitToFirst(20);
query.once('value',(snapshot)=>{...});
```

Database looks like :

```
allUsers 

 anUserUid 
  name: "a Name"
  ...otherinfos...

 anOtherUserUid 
  name: "other Name"
  ...otherinfos...

 ...otherusers...
```

The query returns what I want, but I have an error on each query only saying "@firebase/database:". And nothing else...

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add the log where there is @firebase/database

Comment: That sounds unexpected, but it's hard to be sure with the information you provided. Can you add the full error message and stack trace (as Peter requested)? It would also be great if you could reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin/stackblitz, so that we can all have a look at it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is a warning about no index. 
Try adding an index to your data. You can do that by adding the following to the `database.rules.json` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "allUsers": {
      ".indexOn": ["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

And deploying.

Or by editing the rules in the Firebase Console.

As described in the [indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) documentation page